# How to control my sinuses when I lose my handkerchief

Tags: cleaning, substitute-tool, personal-care, dust

I am living in middle east, so it is common around here to develop sinuses.
I have been affected by it for so long I can't remember feeling well.

I lost my handkerchief and there is not a single tissue paper around a mile, no restroom within sight. I have to save myself from embarrassment. What should I use to blow my nose? I feel like if I don't blow my nose, my nose will stop taking in air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Find an empty open space (preferably with no one looking)
- Close one nostril with your finger, inhale deeply and then shoot the snot out of the other nostril. Make sure you shoot it out with as much force as possible to prevent your face from getting messed up.
- Repeat the process with the other nostril.
- If you have a bottle of water with you, you could use that to clean up after you're done.

Additionally, for blocked sinuses, I would suggest doing a nose wash every morning. You can gt to know more about it here: http://www.webmd.com/allergies/tc/saltwater-washes-nasal-saline-lavage-or-irrigation-for-sinusitis-topic

Comment: This tactic is commonly used by bikers as well.